Prove or disprove: $f: D \to \mathbb{R}$ is injective iff $G_{x_0}$ is injective for every fixed $x_0 \in D$
Conjecture:
Assume the following:

$D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is any non-degenerate interval and $0 \in D$. For example: $D = [0,2\pi]$ or $D = (-10, \infty)$.

The function $f: D \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and non-constant on the whole interval $D$.

For every fixed $x_0 \in D$, let $g: D \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined as $g_{x_0}(x) := f(x-x_0)+f(x) -f(x_0)$.

For every nonempty sets $X$ and $Y$ with $A \subseteq X$, denote $\mathcal{P}(X)$ the as power set of $X$ and define the function $f^{\to}: \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(Y)$ as the image of $A$ under $f$; that is, $f^{\to}(A) := \{f(a) : a \in A\}$ for some function $f: X \to Y$.

Finally, set $G_{x_0}: D \to g^{\to}_{x_0}(D)$ defined by $G_{x_0}(x) := g_{x_0}(x)$.


Then $f$ is injective iff $G_{x_0}$ is bijective for every fixed $x_0 \in D$.
Edit: I made some effort before this post was closed forever. I will prove the $\Leftarrow$ because I think I got it.
Attempt:
Proof:
$\Rightarrow$: Suppose $f$ is injective. This means that if $x \neq y$, then $f(x) \neq f(y)$. WLOG, suppose $x <y$.
WLOG, suppose $f$ is strictly increasing. Then $f(x) < f(y)$ and $f(x -x_0) < f(y - x_0)$ (because $x-x_0 < y - x_0$). So, $g(x) = f(x-x_0) + f(x) - f(x_0) < f(y-x_0) + f(y) - f(x_0) = g(y)$. Thus, $g(x) \neq g(y)$. When $f$ is strictly decreasing can be proved similarly just by changing the "$<$" to the "$>$" symbol.
$\Leftarrow:$ Suppose $G_{x_0}$ is bijective. Notice that $G_{x_0}$ is always surjective because for any $y \in g^{\to}(D)$, there is an $x \in D$ such that $y = g_{x_0}(x)$. So, $G_{x_0}(x)$ is the corresponding preimage as $G_{x_0}(x) = g_{x_0}(x) = y$. Therefore, we only need to prove that if $g_{x_0}$ is injective, so is $f$. Fix $x_0 \in D$. Suppose $x,y \in D$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$. Therefore, for all $x \in D$
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= f(y)\\
f(x)-f(x_0) &= f(y) - f(x_0)\\
f(x-x_0)+f(x)-f(x_0) &= f(x-x_0) + f(y) - f(x_0)\\
g_{x_0}(x) &= f(x-x_0) + f(y) - f(x_0)
\end{align}
$$
Case 1: $x_0 = 0$. Then,
$$
\begin{align}
g_0(x) &= f(x) + f(y) - f(0) \\
&= 2f(y) -f(0)\\
&= f(y-0) + f(y) - f(0)\\
&= g_0(y)
\end{align}
$$
So, we have that if $f(x) = f(y)$, then $g_0(x) = g_0(y)$ which implies
$G_0(x) = G_0(y)$. Thus, by the injectivity of $G_{x_0}$, it implies that $x=y$.
Case 2: $x_0 \neq 0$. Here we will prove it by contradiction. Suppose $x \neq y$, but $f(x) = f(y)$. Since $f$ is continuous on $D$ (more specifically at $x_0 \in D$), it means that given any $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta > 0$ such that for all $\tilde{x} \in D$, if $0< |\tilde{x} - x_0| < \delta$, then $|f(\tilde{x}) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$. Set $x_0 = x-y$, $\epsilon = |x_0|$, and $\tilde{x} = 0$. Choose $\delta > \epsilon > 0$. Then, if $0<|0 - (x-y)| = |x-y| = |x_0| < \delta$, then $$|f(\tilde{x}) - f(x_0)| = |f(0) - f(x-y)| < \epsilon = |x_0| < \delta$$
Since $x, y \in D$ was arbitrarily chosen, it implies that $\delta$ is incredibly small. It must follow that $f(0) = f(x-y)$. Hence,
$$\begin{align}
f(0) &= f(x_0 - x_0) + f(x_0) - f(x_0)\\
&= g_{x_0}(x_0)\\
&= f(x_0 - x_0) + f(y) - f(x_0)\\
&= f(0) + f(y) - f(x-y)\\
&= f(y)
\end{align}$$
But, since $y \in D$ was arbitrarily chosen, $f$ has to be constant. But, we assumed that $f$ was non-constant, which is a contradiction. So, $x =y$. $\square$
Question:
Is the prove above correct for the $\Leftarrow$ direction?
Edit2 Let $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_{\text{std}})$ be the standard topological space and $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $(X, \tau_{X})$ be the subtopological space on $X$. That is, $\tau_X = \{X \cap U : U \in \tau\}$. Then, $X$ is connected iff whenever $S \subseteq X$ with $\partial S = \emptyset$, then $S = X$ or $S = \emptyset$.

$D$ is a connected interval? Do you know any disconnected interval?

Yoyos, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read this thread and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed because it is a very low-quality question.

Yoyos, if you do not put any attempts and efforts in order to solve your problem, your post will be closed very soon.

@JoséCarlosSantos Consider the interval $D = (0,1) \cup (2,3)$. This interval is disconnected.

That's not an interval.

@JoséCarlosSantos actually you're right. Let me edit my post to reduce redundancy.

When doing continuity with $\epsilon$-$\delta$, we can choose $\epsilon$ freely and get, by continuity, a guarantee that some $\delta$ exists. Stronger, we get a guarantee that some $\tau(\epsilon)$ exists such that any choice $\delta\in [0,\tau(\epsilon))$ works. That means we can restrict $\delta$ to be smaller than some constraint, but we can not restrict $\delta$ to be bigger than some constraint unless we show explicitly that we can always find such a $\delta$.

I'm also having trouble following your argument "Since x,y∈D
was arbitrarily chosen, it implies that δ
is incredibly small".
You seem to want to show that $f(x-y)=f(0)$ using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method. But for that you need to show that for every chosen $\epsilon$, the corresponding existing $\delta$ is the same

One way to prove the reverse direction is as follows:
We show the contraposition
$$
f \text{ not injective } \Rightarrow \exists x_0\in D: G_{x_0} \text{ not injective }
$$
So let $x\neq y$ be such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Then $G_0(x)=G_0(y)$ and we're done.

Great answer! Can you make a proof or disproof from above? If so, I'll make your answer as the best answer and accept it. All I want to know is if my conjecture is true or not.

@YoyosTutoring Your proof for ⇒ is correct, and the last section of my answer is a proof for ⇐. So both cases are shown and the proof is complete.

Thank you so much for your help!

I shall call this the Giusti-ConnFus Theorem HAHHA.
